# Cellulase Sample Digestion Protocol?

Tags: enzymes, digestion, protocol

**Is there an effective way to use cellulase(s) and/or lignase(s) to remove unwanted plant debris from a sample?**

I'm working with a series of fresh water grab samples for environmental assessment. The objective is to separate out the benthic invertebrates as a proxy for biodiversity and habitat health. We use 500 micron mesh to remove the bulk of the sediments but this leaves several liters of fine plant material in a variety of stages of decomposition. While searching through yet another petridish of rotting sphagnum I wondered if there might not be a better way to do this?

Is there an effective protocol for decomposing the plant matter using some mixture of cellulases and lignases? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! No experience with this but I would guess that cellulase treatment would be far too slow and I wouldn't have thought there was much lignin in sphagnum. Are these samples of living organisms or have they been fixed in some way? If live, could you use a variation of the technique I've seen where leaf litter is heated in funnels? Maybe you could try using noxious chemicals or heat to drive the invertebrates from the sphagnum slurry?

Comment: Thanks tyresome. The samples aren't entirely sphagnum and have a healthy amount of grasses, leaves, etc. Pretty much a stew of anything that fell into or grew in the river. The critters have been preserved in ethanol and are hopefully dead.

Comment: You could try experimenting with enzymes on some samples you've already analyzed — if you find something that works publish it and post your answer here!  The only alternative I can think of is if you could find a stain that was selective for invertebrates (I was thinking about chitin, but then realized your samples must be riddled with fungi). Good luck!